# creating HTML file for Excel from mysql results - greek characters are displayed as symbols

Tags: php, export-to-excel

I get results from mysql database, and I am creating excel file. However, while english characters are displayed corectly, greek characters are displayed as symbols (unreadable).

Here is the code that I have at this time:

```
//function cleanData(&$str){ 
    // replace fields that _ACCOUNT_DELETE and turn Capital letters into small
    //$str=strtolower($str);
//}

// file name for download 
$filename = "customers" . date('Ymd') . ".xls";
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"");
header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: utf-8');

$flag = false;
$query="SELECT * FROM customers";
$result = mysql_query($query);
while(false !== ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))){
    if(!$flag){
    // display field/column names as first row
        echo "Customers\n";
        $flag = true; 
    } 
    //array_walk($row, 'cleanData'); 
    echo implode("\t", array_values($row)) . "\n";
}
```

Database encoding is `latin1_swedish_ci`

Any help will be deeply appreciated.

Comment: Why do you have such a db encoding? Why don't you try to change the default encoding to a `utf8` equivalent? Something like `utf8_general_ci`

Comment: This is not an Excel file, it's a HTML file that Excel will import. Just so we're clear on the nomenclature

Comment: it is an old database created by someone else, so have no idea why they give it such encoding. I will have manually to re-enter all the records if i change the encoding.

Answer (score 0):

execute this query first.

```
mysql_query( "SET NAMES utf8");
```

And use htmlentities before echoing them.

```
echo htmlentities($data);
```

I dont know about this but you might try

```
 mysql_set_charset('utf8');
```

Comment: i add the mysql_query( "SET NAMES utf8"); above of my select query and i add echo htmlentities($row); above of the echo implode("\t", array_values($row)) . "\n"; 

What i get is different set of symbols instead of greek characters however.

Comment: +1 for set names, -1 for htmlentities. htmlentities will not be needed if things are done properly.

Comment: htmlentities was for encoding special characters.

Comment: @Pekka, well i understand that. From my personal experience, htmlentities has saved me from few deadly situations. So i thought it might make some difference in this case.

Comment: I tried with all the variants above, but hothing work. symbols all over the place, instead of greek characters....

Comment: As a sidenote, when using `htmlentities()`, makes sure you also specify the encoding: `htmlentities($string, ENT_QUTOES, 'UTF-8')`.